# happen on Fridays

Tags: meaning, nouns

a. Good things happen on Fridays.

b. Good things do happen on Fridays.

Do the above sentences mean

1. Good things only happen on Fridays.
2. Only good things happen on Fridays.

or

3. Some good things happen on Fridays. Maybe some bad things happen on Fridays too.

?

Many thanks.

Comment: (1) and (2) are patently untrue,  so (a) would only be said with reference to a particular category of 'good thing', obviously not intending to imply a universal rule. The addition of _do_  adds emphasis, as though contradicting someone who had claimed that good things never happen on Fridays.

Answer (score 2):

Both mean the same thing.  The second one seems to add “do” to reinforce the idea that good things happen on Fridays, but it's not a necessary addition.

The statements themselves don’t say anything instructive without some context.  They only confirm that good things have been known to happen on Fridays.   They say nothing of whether bad things may also happen on that day nor whether good or bad things might happen on any other day.

The intent of the phrases would likely be to mean that Friday is generally considered a favorable day.  In many western cultures, at least, Friday often marks the last working day of a week.  So Friday is often viewed as a happier day than much of the week because it begins transitioning into the weekend, where your time is for your own wants and needs and not for your occupation.  In this meaning, saying good things happen on Fridays is indicating that Fridays tend to be positive and days where you are more likely to enjoy them more than other days, especially other work days.